# how to get text aligned left from input box

Tags: html, css

please check the result here:http://jsfiddle.net/2zjv6jcp/

the problem is that on the top i have a select box and because that box  is smaller than the other textboxes (and not 80% width) the text below it (straatnaam en nummer) won't be shown and also as you can see all the labels are one up (like contactpersoon is shown before Plaats)
how can i align everything good?

Hi currently i have this in a fieldset:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="formWrapper">
        <form id="msform">
            <fieldset id="fieldset3">
                <h2 class="fs-title">Aflevergegevens</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Stap 3: Aflevergegevens</h3>
                <div class="fs-error"></div> 
                <label for="locationLabel">Locatie</label>
                <select  name="locations">
                    <option>test</option>
                </select>
                <label for="addressLabel" style="float:left;">Straatnaam en nummer</label><input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Straatnaam en nummer" />
                <label for="postalCodeLabel">Postcode</label><input type="text" name="postalCode" id="postalCode" placeholder="Postcode" />
                <label for="placeLabel">Plaats</label><input type="text" name="place" id="place" placeholder="Plaats" />
                <label for="contactPersonLabel">Contactpersoon</label><input type="text" name="contactPerson" id="contactPerson" placeholder="Contactpersoon" />
                <br/>
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Vorige" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />   
                <h2>JSON</h2>
                <pre id="result">
                </pre>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

please check the result here:http://jsfiddle.net/2zjv6jcp/

the problem is that on the top i have a select box and because that box  is smaller than the other textboxes (and not 80% width) the text below it (straatnaam en nummer) won't be shown and also as you can see all the labels are one up (like contactpersoon is shown before Plaats)
how can i align everything good?

Comment: Do you want 'Locatie' label to be placed opposite select or 'straatnaam en nummer'?

Comment: The best way is to arrange this in table format. Then it will align properly.

Comment: You have missed this '>' in option tag on line number 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the fiddle to solve some of your problems:
http://jsfiddle.net/2zjv6jcp/19/

**Code-Examples:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <label for="address" style="float:left;">Straat/No</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Straatnaam en nummer" />
</div>

#fieldset1 label,#fieldset3 label
{
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    line-height:45px;
}
```

**Changes:**

- Wrapper around the elements,
- Corrected the label-fors (has to be exact like the input/select),
- Line-height for labels (will center it vertically),
- Paddings/margins and font for inputs/selects,
- Shortend the labels.

**Edit:**
I restructured the code to use less div-wrapper:
http://jsfiddle.net/2zjv6jcp/19/

Comment: it works, but i think it's not a nice solution to create so much divs

Comment: You're right. It's the fast solution. You can also remove much more of the styles...

Comment: bboni, I restructured the wrapper-logic - please recheck.

Answer (score 0):

There exists an aversion towards using tables for formatting HTML components, rightly so due to abundant abuse in the past, but the point still stands: if you want something to be formatted as a table, then use a table.

Thus, my solution (plus some fiddling to make the input and select elements more uniform):
http://jsfiddle.net/fvmasq9z/

If you really (REALLY) despise tables, you can use blocks (like `<div>`) to wrap each line (meaning: input field and related label), give the labels a fixed width and the input fields the remainder to simulate two visual columns.

Better yet, you can substitute the row-`<div>`s with just a `<br>` tag at the end of each line, then give all labels the same fixed width and again the input fields the remainer of the line width.

```css
/*custom font*/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#formWrapper {
  min-height: 494px;
}
#mhead {
  font-family: Georgia !important;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: georgia;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
/*form styles*/

#msform {
  /* font of the form */
  font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  /*----------------------->1*/
  position: relative;
}
#msform select {
  /*float:left;*/
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 29px;
}
#todu {
  font-size: 7pt;
  color: red;
  padding-left: 65px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 55px;
}
#todu2 {
  font-size: 7pt;
  color: red;
  padding-left: 65px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 105px;
}
#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  /*----------------------->2*/
  position: absolute;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
#fieldset3 table {
  width: 100%;
}
#fieldset3 table td {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#fieldset3 table td:first-child {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
#fieldset3 table td input,
#fieldset3 table td select {
  width: 100%;
}
#fieldset1 label,
#fieldset3 label {
  width: 20%;
  /*float:left;*/
  margin-top: 10px;
}
/*inputs*/

#msform input,
#msform textarea,
#msform select {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#msform textarea {
  min-height: 110px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#bijlageTD input[type="file"] {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  border: 0px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 150px;
}
/*buttons*/

#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27AE60;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
#msform .tableProgressForm textarea {
  height: 110px;
}
.tableProgressForm {
  clear: both;
}
/*headings*/

.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
  background: #013b7a;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/

/*progress bar line*/

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #013b7a;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: 1;
  /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/

/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #27AE60;
  color: white;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.success {
  color: green;
}
.statusHead1 {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bfcfdf;
}
#message {
  padding-top: 200px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 7;
  -moz-border-radius: 7;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 18px 7px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*space between the toggle button and showing manual and catalogus order box. */

.manualOrderBox {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.catalogusOrderBox {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.amountBox {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="formWrapper">
    <form id="msform">
      <fieldset id="fieldset3">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Aflevergegevens</h2>

        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Stap 3: Aflevergegevens</h3>

        <div class="fs-error"></div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="locationLabel">Locatie</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select name="locations">
                <option>test</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="addressLabel">Straatnaam en nummer</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Straatnaam en nummer" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="postalCodeLabel">Postcode</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="postalCode" id="postalCode" placeholder="Postcode" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="placeLabel">Plaats</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="place" id="place" placeholder="Plaats" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="contactPersonLabel">Contactpersoon</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="contactPerson" id="contactPerson" placeholder="Contactpersoon" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Vorige" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it also possible to float the table to the left side?

Comment: The table is using all available space inside its parent, so where do you want to table to float to?

Comment: everything now shows at the right side, but the text must begin in the left side

Comment: To align text, use the `text-align:` property in CSS. The `float:` property is used not to align text, but to make block elements (like `<div>`, `<section>` and `<img>`) break free from the natural order of their existence in the code and instead 'float' freely towards one of the sides, making the surrounding blocks or lines wrap around it where possible. To make the labels' text align left instead of right, change `text-align:` to `left;` in the selector `#fieldset3 table td:first-child { ... }`. I did it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/24nzjpev/